# ruby run code in separate process from webapp

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, multithreading, process, multiprocessing

I have a file with worker class (worker.rb) and I need to instantiate it in separate process from rails application after getting the command. I'm currently working on windows os.

So how to do that?

P.S. Will that code work in unix/linux env?

Answer (score 3):

Check out `foreman`

https://github.com/ddollar/foreman

You can put a `Procfile` in your Rails root with instructions for starting both your rails server and your worker and then run `foreman start` to launch them.  Here is a sample Procfile:

```
web: bundle exec unicorn_rails -p 8088
scheduler: bundle exec rake resque:scheduler
worker: bundle exec rake resque:work
```

Foreman is compatible with both Windows and Linux, so it should work regardless of your platform.